# Conditional env proxy?

Tags: bash, proxy, bashrc

I have the following proxy info in my bash_profile:

```
export http_proxy=http://work.proxy.address.com:8080
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy="localhost,.workURL.com"
```

This allows me to run stuff like Homebrew without having to switch my wifi at work (we have two wifi networks--one is proxied). The issue is if I'm at home and not connected to the proxy, I can't use Homebrew or push commits to Github unless I comment out the proxy stuff.

Is it possible to conditionally use these proxy env variables based on the network I'm connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're talking about homebrew I will assume you are using a mac.  You can use airport to get your SSID and then make a conditional on that.  I have the following:

```
export CURR_SSID="$(airport -I | awk '$1 ~ "^SSID"{print $2}' | tr -d " ")"
```

I'm deleting the whitespace for reasons but that isn't really necessary.

Then you could make a conditional based on that:

```
if [[ $CURR_SSID == 'workSSID' ]]; then
  export http_proxy=http://work.proxy.address.com:8080
  export https_proxy=$http_proxy
  export no_proxy="localhost,.workURL.com"
fi
```

Comment: Do I have to reload my shell each time I change networks?

Comment: No problem, glad it helps.  You would need to reload your shell or at least source your bash_profile when you change networks.  I use an alias to make that more simple: `alias reload='source ~/.bash_profile'`

Comment: I have an alias for that already--but in my case at least, I have to open a new shell after switching wifi for the proxy env to be loaded or not. Not a big deal to me. Thanks again!